# How can I find if an utf-8 string contains characters of certain language?

Tags: c++, string, utf-8

I am dealing with utf8 string using c++. I've found that certain language characters have a coding scope in utf-8, such as the scope of Chinese charaters is u4E00 - u9FFF.

But how can I find if a given utf-8 string contains Chinese using C++?

Comment: You can't, because characters and language are not necessarily strictly related. What language is  a part of? Even the block you're talking about can be used natively in one of at least 4 different languages.

Comment: are these characters 中, 十... Chinese, Japanese, Korean or Vietnamese?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc it depends. Briefly speaking, since Japan is close to China, they have cultural cummunications in history, so Chinese has influenced some part of Japanese. If these words appear in Japan contex or alongside the words like some Japan only words like "サービスは", they are Japan. Otherwise they are Chinese.